# Javascript - window.location.href and window.location.replace do not function when an ID is added to the end of the url on the same page

Tags: javascript

I am creating a comment form that posts a comment, receives a response from the server with the ID of the comment, then redirects the user to the comment page where the comment is located. Here is what I have tried:

1. window.location.href = `http://localhost:5000/image/${imgId}#c${res.data.comment_id}`;
2. window.location.replace(`http://localhost:5000/image/${imgId}#c${res.data.comment_id}`);

Where imgId is the id of the comments section and res.data.comment_id is the id of the comment itself.

Neither of these work. When I use the url without the ID attached (i.e. window.location.href = `http://localhost:5000/image/${imgId}`), the page loads properly though it doesn't automatically scroll to the comment like I want. It should be noted that the comment form and the comment section are on the same page. It should also be noted that when I visit the url from different page, it *does* work as intended. I also tried adding the following

window.location.reload();

after the two examples I gave, which does properly refresh the page, but does not automatically redirect the user to the comment like I am trying to do.

I should also mention that when I isolate the form (which is a React app) on a different location (i.e. localhost:3000), the page redirects properly. For some reason, when the form is on the same page that it is supposed to redirect to, it does not redirect when there is an id attached to the end.

Comment: Use `window.location.hash = "#c${res.data.comment_id}"`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this had the same effect as the two examples I gave (added the hashtag to the url but did not load the page with the new comment)

Comment: It works well for me. Try running `window.location.hash = "#answers"` in the console in this page and you'll see it's working fine.

Comment: That's because #answers is already loaded on the page. I am trying to essentially reload the page and put the user at a newly generated element.

Comment: My guess is that the comment element is not rendered on the server side thus is not properly scrolled into view for the user. In that case, you can get the element and use the `scrollIntoView` function.

Comment: The comment is rendered on the server because the page refresh does not happen until the comment is written into the database and the server sends a response with the new comment id. When I leave the id off of the end of the url, the page refreshes with the new comment on the page though it does not scroll to the comment. When I put the id on the end, the page does not refresh though when I copy/paste it into another tab, it works properly. Trying to figure out how to make it work in Javascript.